# Do a diff between csv column and ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a simple csv (a list of emails) that I want to upload to my rails backend API which looks like this:

```
abd@gmail.com,cool@hotmail.com
```

What I want is to upload that file, check in the user table if there are matching rows (in terms of the email address) and then return a newly downloadable csv with 2 columns: the email and whether or not the email was matched to an existing user(boolean true/false).

I'd like to stream the output since the file can be very large. This is what I have so far:

*controller*

```
  def import_csv
    send_data FileIngestion.process_csv(
      params[:file]
    ), filename: 'processed_emails.csv', type: 'text/csv'
  end
```

*file_ingestion.rb*

```
require 'csv'
class FileIngestion

  def self.process_csv(file)
    emails = []
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      emails << row[0]
    end
    users = User.where("email IN (?)", emails)
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Generate the new csv file (stream) with emails and whether or not they there is a match. `users` has all the object that match but now need to create a new csv with all the emails from the old one and whether or not they matched. This is a huge file so I'd like it to be efficient (if possible)

Comment: JFYI, even though `CSV.foreach` is "streaming", you're undoing all of the efficiency by collecting all emails in the same in-memory array.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yup I figured I needed to show something. But an acceptable answer would be one that improves this code. If you have a good solution let me know. I want to avoid over-querying the db and reduce memory allocation as much as possible.

Comment: @Cyzanfar: yes, of course. I would probably choose a middle ground here: group source emails in small-ish batches (100-1000 emails) and query users when batch is full. This way you don't slurp the whole file at once, and you don't query each email individually.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the feedback. Would you how I could generate a new CSV with the data?

Comment: @Cyzanfar: you can generate csv using one of these: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Writing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168300/discussion-between-cyzanfar-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pluck all the emails from the Users and do something like this. This example keeps it simple but you get the idea. If we can assume your input file is just a string of emails with comma separated values then this should work:

```
emails = File.read('emails.csv').split(',')

def process_csv(emails)
  user_emails = User.where.not(email: [nil, '']).pluck(:email)
  CSV.open('emails_processed.csv', 'w') do |row|
    row << ['email', 'present']
    emails.each do |email|
      row << [email, user_emails.include?(email) ? 'true' : 'false']
    end
  end
end

process_csv(emails)
```

UPDATED to match your code design:

```
def import_csv
  send_data FileIngestion.process_csv(params[:file]), 
    filename: 'processed_emails.csv', type: 'text/csv'
end

require 'csv'
class FileIngestion

  def self.process_csv(file)
    emails = File.read('emails.csv').split(',')
    CSV.open('emails_processed.csv', 'w') do |row|
      emails.each do |email|
        row << [email, user_emails.include?(email) ? 'true' : 'false']
      end
    end
    File.read('emails_processed.csv')
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a solution. How do I get the file to download on my computer once it's done? I'm using a curl command to make the request: `curl -F file=@wb.csv http://localhost:3000/api/v1/process_data\?api_key\=Dp9Kv7j1y-FYytd-tYsAsSNic3ox`. Although this is pretty much the same in terms of memory. The file is very large and with this code likely to run out of memory

Comment: The input, and therefore also the output file.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to do is collect the incoming CSV data into batches - use each batch to query the database and write a diff to a tempfile.

You would then stream the tempfile to the client.

```
require 'csv'
require 'tempfile'

class FileIngestion

  BATCH_SIZE = 1000

  def self.process_csv(file)
    csv_tempfile = CSV.new(Tempfile.new('foo'))
    CSV.read(file, headers: false).lazy.drop(1).each_slice(BATCH_SIZE) do |batch|
      emails = batch.flatten
      users = User.where(email: emails).pluck(:email)
      emails.each do |e|
        csv_tempfile << [e, users.include?(e)]
      end
    end
    csv_tempfile
  end
end
```

`CSV.read(file, headers: false).lazy.drop(1).each_slice(BATCH_SIZE)` uses a [lazy enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) to access the CSV file in batches. `.drop(1)` gets rid of the header row.

Comment: I like this solution! Only thing it throws an error (`ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+))`) at this line: `csv_tempfile = CSV.new(Tempfile.new)` would need to pass a filename to it.

Comment: Thats odd - I tried it on `2.3.1p112` and I'm not getting an error. Try calling `Tempfile.new('foo')` instead.

Comment: yup. Also missing a `batch.length` but that's minor. Also how do I then get the file to download to my computer? I thought send_data in my controller would take care of that

Comment: I think you can just set the response body to be the returned CSV file. Since its an enumerable Rails can stream it on its own. https://medium.com/table-xi/stream-csv-files-in-rails-because-you-can-46c212159ab7

Comment: tried that but the file is not downloading to my computer don't know what's going on

Comment: I found a far more elegant way of doing it with [Lazy Enumerators](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html). Edited.

Comment: Make sure you're sending the correct headers, especially `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"` otherwise the client will treat it as inline and just display the whole stream.

Comment: I did that: `headers["Content-Disposition"] =
           %(attachment; filename="result_file.csv")` but no luck

Comment: How are you testing it? With a browser or cURL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168323/discussion-between-cyzanfar-and-max).

Comment: With curl: `curl -F file=@wb.csv http://localhost:3000/api/v1/process_data\?api_key\=Dp9Kv7j1y-FYytd-tYsAsSNic3ox`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what I came up with. A solution that basically prevents users from uploading a file that has more than 10,000 data points. Might not be the best solution (I prefer @Max's one) but in any case wanted to share what I did:

```
  def emails_exist
    raise 'Missing file parameter' if !params[:file]
    csv_path = params[:file].tempfile.path
    send_data csv_of_emails_matching_users(csv_path), filename: 'emails.csv', type: 'text/csv'
  end

  private

  def csv_of_emails_matching_users(input_csv_path)
    total = 0
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |result|
      result << %w{email exists}
      emails = []
      CSV.foreach(input_csv_path) do |row|
        total += 1
        if total > 10001
          raise 'User Validation limited to 10000 emails'
        end
        emails.push(row[0])
        if emails.count > 99
          append_to_csv_info_for_emails(result, emails)
        end
      end
      if emails.count > 0
        append_to_csv_info_for_emails(result, emails)
      end
    end
  end

  def append_to_csv_info_for_emails(csv, emails)
    user_emails = User.where(email: emails).pluck(:email).to_set
    emails.each do |email|
      csv << [email, user_emails.include?(email)]
    end
    emails.clear
  end
```